# Reemplazo del método .on() en jQuery 1.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

Estoy trabajando con [tinymce](/questions/tagged/tinymce), una librería en Javascript para convertir los elementos `<textarea>`en editores web. Esta librería requiere jQuery para funcionar. La versión de jQuery disponible en el proyecto en este momento es la 1.5, que por razones de compatibilidad y de código legado no puedo actualizar. Para configurar una opción en [tinymce](/questions/tagged/tinymce) y permitir que los elementos `<textarea`> se actualicen con la información ingresada antes de enviarlo a través de un `<form>` me indican adiciona este código:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    statusbar: false,
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('change', function () {
            tinymce.triggerSave();
        });
    }
});
```

El inconveniente ocurre con la variable setup, al asociarlo con la función anónima obtengo un error porque el método `.on()` no está disponible en mi versión de jQuery. ¿De qué forma puedo convertir esa función para adaptarme a la versión de jQuery que tengo? Ya probé con `.live()`, `.delegate()` y `.bind()` y no obtengo la funcionalidad esperada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intentaste usando directo el nombre de la funcion `change`

```
setup: function (editor) {
    editor.change(function () {
        tinymce.triggerSave();
    });
}
```

Si eso no funciona usar el `onChange`

[tinymce.Editor.onChange](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:event.tinymce.Editor.onChange)

En el ejemplo define

```
 tinyMCE.init({
   ...
   setup : function(editor) {
         editor.onChange.add(function(ed, l) {...
```

Comment: Sobre la primera respuesta, lo intenté y ya no me arroja errores, pero sigo sin obtener el resultado esperado. Sobra la segunda respuesta no es posible usar el método onChange porque según la API de esa versión se ejecuta cuando se quiere realizar una acción tipo 'undo' en el área de texto. Aún así estoy viendo la documentación del API 4.x. Gracias.